# IndexError: string index out of range (enumerate)

Tags: python, python-3.x

Okay so I have no idea what the problem is here.  Everything I've read basically addresses the range not ending, thus the error, but that doesn't make sense to me since this is a fixed loop.

I'm simply trying to take a string, and throw each letter into a list one at a time.  What am I missing?

```
>>> name = "Chris"
>>> 
>>> my_list = []
>>> 
>>> for key, value in enumerate(name):
...     my_list.append(value[key])
...     print (my_list)
...
```

The error I'm receiving:

```
['C']
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<pyshell#7>", line 2, in <module>
 my_list.append(value[key])
IndexError: string index out of range
```

Answer (score 2):

What you are missing is that `value` is a single element string. Indexing at positions `!= 0` will result in an `IndexError`; during your first iteration that's what happens.

If you want to create it with your for loop, just append the value immediately:

```
for key, value in enumerate(name):
    my_list.append(value)
```

Of course, `enumerate` is by no means required here, this can be simplified by calling `list` and supplying the string in question; Python will then create a list containing the contents of the string for you:

```
my_list = list(name)
```

For `Python 3.x` you can also unpack in a `list` literal with `*`:

```
my_list = [*name]
```

In all supplied snippets, the result of the operations is `['C', 'h', 'r', 'i', 's']` as required.

Answer (score 0):

```
name = 'Chris'
my_list = list(name)
print(my_list)
```

Input: ['C', 'h', 'r', 'i', 's']

For one in each time:

```
for letter in name:
print(letter)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are enumerating over a string ("Chris") which means that key and value will hold the following values during the iteration:

```
0  "C"
1  "h"
2  "r"
3  "i"
4  "s"
```

value[key] in the first iteration is ok, it returns 'C'.

In the second iteration, the index 1 is out of range for string "h".

What you probably want to do is this:

```
for i, value in enumerate(name):
   my_list.append(value)
   print (my_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

change  `my_list.append(value[key])` to `my_list.append(value)` in your code

Answer (score 0):

An alternative way, to reach your goal:

```
>>>name ="Chris"
>>>list(name)
['C', 'h', 'r', 'i', 's']
```

For your example:
When iterating through a string in python, no enumeration is required.

```
>>>name = "Chris"
>>>my_list = []
>>>for i in name:
...  my_list.append(i)
>>>my_list
['C', 'h', 'r', 'i', 's']
```